# i have this error when i send post request in postman

Tags: php, laravel

i get error when i send request in post man

the error:
ErrorException: Undefined array key "value" in file

thw code:

```
public function search(Request $request) {
    $request = $request->all();

    $models = Course::query()
            ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request['value'] . '%')
            ->where(['deleted' => '0'])
            ->get();
    return response()->json($models);
}
```

Comment: have you checked the content of `$reques`

Answer (score 3):

Dump out your `$request` and have a look at it, like :

```php
dd($request);
```

You probably want to access the values like :

```php
$request->input('value');
```

instead of trying to access it as an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can make the following changes , so that it works dynamically based on the given

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $request = $request->all();

        $models = Course::query()
            ->when(array_key_exists('value', $request), function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request['value'] . '%');
            })
            ->where(['deleted' => '0'])
            ->get();
        return response()->json($models);
    }
```

here we have when statement to check whether this key exist or not , in case of non existence it won't execute with that particular key else it works as desired.

```
when(array_key_exists('value', $request), function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request['value'] . '%');
        })
```

you can also modify ***when*** statement, or if you want more conditional statement than you can also append those inside the above-mentioned statement.

Answer (score 1):

del one line and use

```
&request->value;
```

like that

```
public function search(Request $request) {
$models = Course::query()
        ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')
        ->where(['deleted' => '0'])
        ->get();
return response()->json($models);
}
```